# Windows phone 8.1, toast notification, globalization and text parameters

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, globalization, toast

I want to send a toast notification (from a server to a windows phone), the notification have to be something like "Katie bought you 3 items", but it have to run in different languages, so I can't writte that directly on the server.

The text comes from the server and you can't catch a notification if the app is not running.

There is a way to do globalization writting "ms-resource:label" but it is a fixed text, or at least in the website of Microsoft I can't see anyway to write something more, so with that the max I can get is something like "Someone bought you N items", without Katie and the number 3.

Can I put parameters in a resource? Something like ms-resource:label#Katie#3
where label is %1 bought you %2 items.

Or maybe there is another way.. How can I send this kind of messages in a toast notification?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting back the channel URI from WNS, when you are sending it to your server (from device), you can also pass device region and language information along with it. While sending notifications to WNS (from server), check these values against every channel URI to create customized text for that respective user.